# How to resolve VBA runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I have these two workbooks.

I want to transfer data of some columns in the first workbook to a given sheet in workbook 2.

I am getting an error of runtime (1004). Method 'Range of object' worksheet failed

I am getting error on this line in the code

```
  SummarySheet.Range(columnaddress & "8:" & columnaddress & lastrow).Copy 
Here's the complete code .
```

```
 Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim MacroBook As Workbook, SummaryBook As Workbook, BSSBook As Workbook, _
    SummarySheet As Worksheet, TwoGonlyER As Worksheet, threeGswapRoll As Worksheet, _
    threeGswapER As Worksheet, fourGprData As Worksheet, threeGpRData As Worksheet
  Dim onlyER As Range, rolloutER As Range, swapER As Range, prData As Range, _
    gPRdata As Range, FolderPathForSummary As String, lastrow As Integer

  Set MacroBook = ThisWorkbook

  'Summary Book Open
  FolderPathForSummary = MacroBook.Worksheets("Tool").Range("D8")

  FolderPath = MacroBook.Worksheets("Tool").Range("D11")

  If Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid folder path to save the file!"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If Not Dir(FolderPathForSummary)  "" Then
    MsgBox " Summary file doesn't exist in your mentioned address. Please   check again!  "
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set SummaryBook = Workbooks.Open(FolderPathForSummary)
  Set SummarySheet = SummaryBook.Worksheets("Summary Data")

  lastrow = SummarySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  'BSS Tracker Open
  Set BSSBook = Workbooks.Add
  BSSBook.SaveAs (FolderPath & "BSS Tracker " & Format(CStr(Now), "ddmmmyyyyhhmmss") & ".xlsx")

  MacroBook.Worksheets("2G Only ER").Copy before:=BSSBook.Sheets(1)
  Set TwoGonlyER = BSSBook.Worksheets("2G Only ER")

  MacroBook.Worksheets("3G Swap & 4G ROllout ER").Copy before:=BSSBook.Sheets(1)
  Set threeGswapRoll = BSSBook.Worksheets("3G Swap & 4G ROllout ER")

  MacroBook.Worksheets("3G & 4G Swap ER").Copy before:=BSSBook.Sheets(1)
  Set threeGswapER = BSSBook.Worksheets("3G & 4G Swap ER")

  MacroBook.Worksheets("4G PR Data").Copy before:=BSSBook.Sheets(1)
  Set fourGprData = BSSBook.Worksheets("4G PR Data")

  MacroBook.Worksheets("3G PR Data").Copy before:=BSSBook.Sheets(1)

  Set threeGpRData = BSSBook.Worksheets("3G PR Data")
  Set swapER = threeGswapER.Range("A3:P3")

  For Each entry In swapER

    columnaddress = entry.Value

    SummarySheet.Range(columnaddress & "8:" & columnaddress & lastrow).Copy
    entry.PasteSpecial

  Next entry

  BSSBook.Save
  BSSBook.Close

  SummaryBook.Save
  SummaryBook.Close

  MsgBox "BSS Tracker successfully generated!"

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `columnaddress` when it crashes?  i.e. what are the contents of cells A3:P3 on sheet "3G PR Data"?  (I'm guessing it isn't a valid Excel column description, i.e. "A" to "XFD".)

Comment: Just before the problem line, create a string variable: Dim s As String, then calculate your range address:  s=columnaddress & "8:" & columnaddress & lastrow  , and then MsgBox s.  See if the address is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Go trough your code with F8 in the Editor and see what the actual Values are.

Comment: Sorry - when I said sheet `"3G PR Data"` before I should have said sheet `"3G & 4G Swap ER"` - so what are the values in `'3G & 4G Swap ER'!A3:P3`.